# "unspecified-fg/bg" in "batch mode" when querying foreground/background colors

Tags: font-lock, themes, batch-mode

While writing tests for `color-identifiers-mode` I stumbled upon inability to make Emacs load background and foreground colors from a theme in "batch-mode".

Example:

```lisp
emacs -batch --eval "(progn (load-theme 'adwaita) (print (face-attribute 'default :foreground)) (print (face-attribute 'default :background)))"

"unspecified-fg"

"unspecified-bg"
```

I presume that in a batch mode I need to flush font-lock, however doing all of the following after theme is loaded:

```lisp
(font-lock-flush)
(font-lock-ensure)
(font-lock-fontify-buffer)
```

has no effect, it's still "unspecified-fg/bg".

So how do I make it load colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs won't initialize the window system when launched by `-batch`:

> When Emacs is started up, it performs the following operations:

> If not running in batch mode, it initializes the window system that ...

> If appropriate, it creates a graphical frame.
> As part of creating the graphical frame, it initializes the window system ...
> This is not done in batch (noninteractive) or daemon mode.

A workaround is to start Emacs normally and then let it make frames *invisible* or *iconified*.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'll ask on ML then to make sure there's no way around. Starting Emacs as usual is something I definitely wouldn't want as part of testing.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: May I ask what ML is?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the mailing list

Comment: Asked it [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2024-02/msg00095.html), Eli replied, it seems like there's no way for that to work in batch mode.